# prevent session logout for 4 hours

Tags: php, session, logout

I am trying to keep the user from being logged out too soon from the session forcing them to log back into the API. Ideally, I would like the user to be prompted to log back in no sooner/later than 4 hours after login.

The attached code shows what I have done so far to address this issue. The observed behavior is that the user will remained logged in as long as they interact with the API frequently (20-30 mins or so). But it they are inactive, they are logged out.

What do I need to change to ensure that my user is logged out exactly 4 hours after logging in?

My Code:

Login:

```
<?php
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "14400");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
session_set_cookie_params(14400);
session_start();

include("inc.php");

// Check that user sent login credentials.
if ((isset($_POST['username'])) and (isset($_POST['password']))) {

    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

} else {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "Credentials did not save. Please try again.";
}

// Connect to the server and database.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_errno) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}

// Grab data from table using provided creds.
if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sched_users WHERE login = ? ORDER BY login LIMIT 1"))) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}

// Bind parameters for safe variable insertion.
if (!($sql->bind_param("s", $login))) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
    //echo json_encode("Binding parameters failed.");
}

// Run statement.
if (!$sql->execute()) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
}

//Get result.
$res = $sql->get_result();


if ($res->num_rows === 0) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "No user record found.";

} else if (!(($res->num_rows === 1) or ($res->num_rows === 0))) {

    // Display error to user.
    echo "Too many results returned.";

} else {

    $row = $res->fetch_array();


    // Check the entered password with the hashed password using PHP's password_verify(). Create session upon success.
    $hash = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {


        //create session variables to use throughout scheduler.
        //Session array name removed from post for security.
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['login'] = $row['login'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['userid'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['phone'] = $row['phone'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['company'] = $row['company'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['department'] = $row['department'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['admin'] = $row['admin'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['statusflag'] = $row['statusflag'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['revoked'] = $row['revoked'];
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['start'] = time();
        // Set session to expire.
        $_SESSION['my_session_name']['expire'] = ($_SESSION['my_session_name']['start'] + (60 * 14400)); 

        //redirect authenticated user to landing page.
        header("location: landing.php");

    } else {
        // Display error to user.
        echo "The username or password does not match. Please try again.";
    }

}

// close connection variables.
$sql->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Example of Code to check session (reused):

```
<?php
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "14400");
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", "0");
session_set_cookie_params(14400);
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['my_session_name']['firstname'])) {

    $cur_time = time();

    if ($cur_time > $_SESSION['my_session_name']['expire']) {

        session_destroy();
        echo 'Your session has expired! <a href="[https://my.url/index.php">Log Back In</a>';

    } else {

        $title = "Hi ".$_SESSION['my_session_name']['firstname']."Please create a new user.";

        $firstname = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['lastname'];
        $login = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['login'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['userid'];
        $email = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['email'];
        $phone = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['phone'];
        $company = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['company'];
        $department = $_SESSION['my_session_name']['department'];

    }

} else {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: https://my.url/index.php");
}
?>
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you!